# My python script which contains infinity loop breaks which I don't want. What to do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a python script which uses selenium and chromedriver to get some info from a website. I have used python scheduler module to make the script run every 2 minute. It runs fine and get the info I want. But, whenever another script scheduled in windows task scheduler gets triggered, this script automatically stops although there is a infinity loop in it. I don't want another script causing this script to stop. How to handle that?

This is how my code is structured.

```
def get_info():
    # code here

schedule.every(2).minutes.until("18:30").do(get_info)


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I want this infinity loop to run for a long time and not interrupted by another task and script scheduled in the windows task scheduler. What should I do? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like an OS problem rather than a python problem

Comment: seems like we'd need to see more code to offer any advice here.   When/where do you initialize the webdriver, and when/where do you tear down?   (sounds like you need to make sure to create a new webdriver instance each time this runs... and keep references to close them when you are done... but be aware that launching 1 browser every 2 minutes is going to clog up your resources very quickly.)

Comment: Yes. I dont want to add a new instance every time it runs the loop. Right now, when no other script is scheduled, it doesn't face any problem and can run the loop and take the info that I want correctly. It can run for hours without any issue. But whenever another task scheduled in the windows task scheduler gets triggered this script stops and come out of a infinite loop which I don't get. You are saying OS can be a problem. So what kind of settings should I do/follow to get rid of this problem?

Comment: include your code for (get_info) seems like that's what is being scheduled here?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.